# Web-scraping the audio and related text form ganjoor site by colab as Persian Speech to text database

Tags: web-scraping

I have tried to gather some audio form [ganjoor site](https://ganjoor.net/hafez/ghazal/sh1/) to gather Audio files with its texts like those contents that is reading by ... shown below:

[image]

By using the google colab, so i have tried different method via this coalb :

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ntSbqv6iSrNt2F8eyWTvao5ED9Ot0szi?usp=sharing

And I get this kind of errors that you can see at above colab page:

[image]

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:29: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-c4b1e303b5e7> in <module>()
     28 
     29 wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
---> 30 wd.get(url)
     31 print(wd.page_source)  # re

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
  (Session info: headless chrome=85.0.4183.83)
```

or
[image]

```
onnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ganjoor.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /hafez/ghazal/sh1/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6e23c5c8d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))
```

So my guess is that this kind of web-scraping needs some proper agent header setting or using some proxy in the setting, and I don't know which header is proper and or what proxy sites or free vpn provider is exist and ...

**Update:**

According to answer of **@baduker**, it seams that there is some problem with colab to connect the https://ganjoor.net site and its showing that error again (the **@baduker** codes added to the [related GitHub colab notebooks page](https://github.com/So-AI-love/Persian-text-to-speech/blob/master/Webscraping_ganjor_audio.ipynb):

[image]

I would be very grateful if you could scrape one audio with its related texts from the ganjoor site, as one example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need the raw power of `Selenium` to get what you're after.

It can be done with `requests, BeautifulSoup, and some re`.

The regex module is useful for fetching all the `.mp3` source urls from the page source. If you look at it you'll see a `<script>` tag with some JavaScript and all the urls you need.

Parse it and download the `.mp3`.

Here's how to do it:

```
import re

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from shutil import copyfileobj

url = "https://ganjoor.net/hafez/ghazal/sh1/"
page = requests.get(url).text

text = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser").find_all("div", {"class": "m2"})
print([t.text.replace("\u200c", "") for t in text])

pattern = re.compile(r"https://i\.ganjoor\.net/a2?/\d+[-a-z]+?\.mp3")
audio_tracks = re.findall(pattern, page)
print(audio_tracks)

for track in audio_tracks:
    print(f"Fetching track: {track}...")
    with requests.get(track, stream=True) as t, \
            open(track.split("/")[-1], "wb") as a:
        copyfileobj(t.raw, a)
```

Output for audio:

```
2130-ak.mp3
2130-az.mp3
2130-ff.mp3
2130-hr.mp3
2130-mfk.mp3
2130-ml.mp3
2130-ng.mp3
2130-zsh.mp3
```

And the text:

```
['که عشق آسان نمود اول ولی افتاد مشکلها', 'ز تاب جعد مشکینش چه خون افتاد در دلها', 'جرس فریاد میدارد که بربندید محملها', 'که سالک بیخبر نبود ز راه و رسم منزلها', 'کجا دانند حال ما سبکباران ساحلها', 'نهان کی ماند آن رازی کز او سازند محفلها', 'متی ما تلق من تهوی دع الدنیا و اهملها']
```

Comment: Thanks, It was a great help to me, but i don't know why it is not working on the colab!, it can be seen [here](http://t.ly/3EDS)

Comment: What is this that you've sent? I'm not familiar with Google Colab. Try running this locally with Python3.

Comment: I have sent the result of above codes in colab, but thanks again and i understand that the ganjoor site is responding and it could be could be done by vps or local pc. that is fixed my problem alot.

Comment: If you find my answer useful, please consider either accepting it or upvoting. Thanks.

Comment: colab is free Ubuntu server to test AI project on it, which you could install GitHub project on it with python and other language ( java and ... need some tricks!). you can test it by clicking on open in colab icon via this [link](https://github.com/So-AI-love/Persian-text-to-speech/blob/master/Ganjoor_aduio_scraper_0.ipynb)

Comment: It is useful around 80% for me, but the issue is still open ( i will wait for some period of days and if ... accept it ), also i am not able to up-vote it because of lack of reputation.

Comment: @sosa you don't have to wait days to accept it. If it's useful, please accept the answer. If something more useful comes up, you can change the accepted answer with one click.